# Remove duplicates from a SQL server rows using DISTINCT

Tags: sql-server, duplicates, distinct

I need to remove SQL server duplicated rows when importing file into database with distinct method.

HallGroup is my table in database. I'm using this
Sql procedure:

```
SELECT  DISTINCT * INTO tempdb.dbo.tmpTable
FROM HallGroup
DELETE FROM HallGroup
INSERT INTO HallGroup SELECT * FROM tempdb.dbo.tmpTable
DROP TABLE tempdb.dbo.tmpTable
```

With this procedure works fine duplicated rows are deleted, but the problem is when i try to import again data to SQL server rows are still duplicating. What i'm missing, So any hint?

How to remove SQL server duplicated rows properly when importing file into database with distinct method?

Comment: So you're seeing duplication with data you've already got in the table? you need to link to that table upon import to ensure you're not duplicating data

Comment: Yes. How to link my table upon import?

Comment: I'd consider having a staging table to load data into (truncate it each time). then do a simple insert with a join

Comment: I tried truncate but effect was the same. I'm new to SQL and don't understand how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

I am just getting back into SQL after being out for a bit but I would not have solved your problem in that way that you are trying (not that I completely understand why you are doing it that way) as I believe (even if it were working correctly) over time your process will take longer each time you do it as the size of the table increases.

It would be much more efficient if you inserted the new data based on the absence of a key (you indicate you are already using a stored proc). If you don't have a key to use (which very recently happened to me), make one. I just solved a similar problem to yours whereas I am importing data into a table from an external source and wanted to eliminate the possibility of duplicates. In my case, I associate name of the external source datafile (is distinct by dataset to import) with the data to be imported and use that to ensure I am not re-importing already imported data. I load the external data into a table using a dtsx and then run a stored proc to merge that data with an existing table. This gives me the added advantage of having a audit trail of where each record came from.

Hope this helps.